# LibreCalc- correspond few columns and rows across sheets

Tags: libreoffice

I'm Libre Calc newbie that never went beyond SUM function. I don't expect help-it's a complex, specified problem. Anyway I need to clarify my mind somewhere, **so**

I have three sheets:

- Governments revenues in domestic currency **(sheetA)**:
  [image: Sheet A]
- exchange rates- US$ per national currency **(sheetB)**,
  [image: Sheet B]
- and a sheet where I need government revenues shown in $dollars **(sheetC)**.

**SheetA** has columns with countries and revenue type listed (central gov/general) and rows with years listed. XY positions are different countries revenues in domestic currency in exact year. I need each XY position to correspond with **SheetB** which has three columns: country name, year and corresponding exchange rate.

Now I need to match **SheetA** country name column and year row with **SheetB** country name and year columns in a way that revenue in domestic currency **A** is multiplied by exchange rate **B** then value is returned to **C**.

*Thus I can't post more than 2 images, **SheetC** is built like **SheetA** - two columns with country name and revenue type (central government/general) and one row with years, giving accurate **SheetA** XY positions (which are empty now).  For curious, if any- next I will compare 2000 private corporations and their factors with countries organisations in a scale of time, and try to make sense of their relative dynamics.*

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/ is more suited for this  ;-) And I would create an example of a few records where you explain what it should do.

Comment: of course, working on progress

Comment: It sounds like nothing more complicated than selecting the corresponding cells from the relevant worksheets when you enter your formula(s) in Sheet C - where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Im stuck at its overview. Problem introduced to ask.libreoffice.org

Comment: You could probably find a tutorial to do this and copy their calc sheets. Then keeping the formulas, paste your own data and recalculate.

Answer (score 0):

It was all about proper formula: =LOOKUP(REVENUE_DOLLAR.D$1,REVENUE_DOMESTIC_CURRENCY.D$1:REVENUE_DOMESTIC_CURRENCY.AU$1,REVENUE_DOMESTIC_CURRENCY.D3:REVENUE_DOMESTIC_CURRENCY.AU3)*SUMIFS(EXCHANGE_RATES.$D$2:EXCHANGE_RATES.$D$10313,EXCHANGE_RATES.$C$2:EXCHANGE_RATES.$C$10313,D$1,EXCHANGE_RATES.$B$2:EXCHANGE_RATES.$B$10313,$B3)